# How can you complete a Debian installation interrupted just before "Finish installation"?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, system-recovery

I am trying to get Debian installed on a device that doesn't have enough battery capacity to power the display on full brightness for long enough to complete an installation, even while plugged in. I've got it to the stage where I've installed almost everything and it was sitting on the penultimate step of the advanced installer, but I didn't press "Finish installation" before the power ran out.

How can I perform the steps that "Finish installation" normally performs in order to get my system working?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I take _even while plugged in_ means the OP is using a power cable.

Comment: Depending how suddenly the power ran out it could cause corruption on your file system. Attempting to pick up where you left off might not succeeded even if it's an option.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Assume that the system was in a stable state; it was on the menu at the time, and I assume that no files on the filesystem were being used and that the installer doesn't cache disk writes.

Comment: Besides the accepted answer, nothings is preventing turning off/dimming out the display during the automatic parts and getting back at it after a while.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's embedded, and the installer doesn't have the drivers / doesn't provide a way of modifying the backlight setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the "Finish the installation" step of the d-i graphical Debian installer it runs scripts out of each parts of the installer. After installing the bootloader however it immediately runs this step. The only step left is the "finish-install" step which is here: https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/finish-install/tree/master/finish-install.d

However if for some reason it does ask you before continuing with finishing up the install then it'd be a mess to go through the dozens of scripts and it'd be better to just reinstall with `preseed` which allows to do most of the install headless with a config file.